# It appears as though you do not have permission to view information for any of the hosts you requested

Tags: nagios

I am getting the above error whilw logged in as nagios admin user.
I am copying the file objects.cache and status.dat from remote server to get the updated to this machine,I am logging in as nagiosadmin below is the cgi.cfg file.

main_config_file=/etc/nagios/nagios.cfg

physical_html_path=/usr/share/nagios/html
url_html_path=/nagios
show_context_help=0
use_pending_states=1

use_authentication=1

use_ssl_authentication=0

default_user_name=guest

authorized_for_system_information=nagiosadmin,admin

authorized_for_configuration_information=*

authorized_for_system_commands=nagiosadmin,admin

authorized_for_all_services=nagiosadmin,admin
authorized_for_all_hosts=nagiosadmin,admin

authorized_for_all_service_commands=nagiosadmin,admin
authorized_for_all_host_commands=nagiosadmin,admin

default_statusmap_layout=5

default_statuswrl_layout=4

## statuswrl_include=myworld.wrl

ping_syntax=/bin/ping -n -U -c 5 $HOSTADDRESS$

refresh_rate=90
result_limit=100

escape_html_tags=1

action_url_target=_blank
notes_url_target=_blank

lock_author_names=1

Comment: I am getting the error only for hosts and service tabs

Comment: after I restart /etc/init.d/nagios restart ,after reloading the nagios,with the default files its working(objects and status.dat)

Comment: But its not working with the files which I am copying from remote server.

Comment: ... why are you trying to copy the status file and object cache between servers?